# How to make an EditText to be focused but not clickable?(Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin.android, android-edittext

I have 3 `EditText`:

```xml
<EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:focusedByDefault="false"
   android:minWidth="25px"
   android:minHeight="25px"
   android:id="@+id/editText1" />
<EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:focusedByDefault="true"
   android:clickable="false"
   android:id="@+id/editText2" />
<EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:focusedByDefault="false"
   android:id="@+id/editText3" />
```

I want when the activity is opened the second `EditText` to be focused(with the cursor blinking in it) but when I tap on it I don't want the keyboard to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example I put together that works for me.  And with this solution, you can remove the "focusedByDefault" and "clickable" attributes from all of your EditText views in your layout file.

```cs
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, View.IOnTouchListener {

    private EditText editText2;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main);
        editText2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText2);
        editText2.RequestFocus();
        editText2.SetOnTouchListener(this);  // Requires addition of View.IOnTouchListener interface to class
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        v.OnTouchEvent(e);
        var imm = (Android.Views.InputMethods.InputMethodManager)v.Context.GetSystemService(InputMethodService);
        imm?.HideSoftInputFromWindow(v.WindowToken, Android.Views.InputMethods.HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        return true;
    }
}
```