# Click event fires when scrolling on EditText to see all its content(Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin.android, android-edittext, click

When I scroll in an `EditText` to see its content when it's too long, its click event fires. How can I prevent that? The EditText is not editable.

Here is my `activity`:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, View.IOnTouchListener
{
    EditText et;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        et = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
        et.SetOnTouchListener(this);
        et.Click += delegate { this.OnClicking(); };
    }

    private void OnClicking()
    {
        //Show alert dialog
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        v.OnTouchEvent(e);
        var imm = (Android.Views.InputMethods.InputMethodManager)v.Context.GetSystemService("input_method");
        imm?.HideSoftInputFromWindow(v.WindowToken, Android.Views.InputMethods.HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is my `axml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:text="Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text "
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/editText1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you could explain what exactly are you doing with the Touch event may be I would be able to suggest an alternate solution!?

Comment: I am making the `EditText` focused but not clickable. Here is the question I asked about how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024589/how-to-make-an-edittext-to-be-focused-but-not-clickablexamarin-android

Comment: If your EditText will have lots of data why not just make multiline?

Comment: The one who ordered the project wants it that way.

Comment: Hi Bonucci, I was the person who answered your other related question.  For this, why can't you just remove the "et.Click += delegate { this.OnClicking(); };" line?  When I remove that line using your code, I am able to freely scroll the EditText content.

Comment: It works but when I click on it I want an alert dialog to appear and it doesn't and if I put the alert dialog in the OnTouch method it appears 3 times.

Comment: Do you want to acheve it like this GIF? https://imgur.com/a/lraijCp, I did not know what you want to acheved. Do you want to prevent click event or other things?